# Declension of America

Tags: склонение

"From America" translates to `из Америки` and I know that из will take the genitive case. `Америка` is a feminine noun (because it ends in `а` and is a place).

To form the genitive case of a singular feminine noun, you replace `а` with `ы`. `Америка` would become `Америкы`.

Why is this not the correct declension?

Comment: Generally, it is very unusual to see `ы` after `к`. The only example which is not a loan word that I can think of is `кыш!`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For nouns which end by -кa,  -а is replaced by -и:

- маска - из маски
- каска - из каски
- рука - из руки
- Америка - из Америки

Comment: Cheers. Would this be correct then? Он приезжает из Америки.

Comment: @Chris G. - yes, its correct.

Comment: The same rule applies (и rather than ы in spelling) after other consonants too: г, ж, х, ч, ш, and щ.  Look up declension tables for книга, кожа, муха, задача, крыша, and пища.

Comment: Where does russian.SE go for declension tables? The places I've looked always seem to miss something...

Comment: @ChrisG. First, you can look the word up in *Wiktionary*. Second, you can find tables here: http://www.public.asu.edu/~deliving/russgram/ and at http://www.alphadictionary.com/rusgrammar/case.html

Comment: Just remember than no table will cover the irregularities. And, really, these tables for regular cases are the most useful ones because they are short and cover the majority of nouns.

Answer (score 6):

The sound shifts *кы > ки*, *гы > ги* and *хы > хи* date back to the 12th or 13th century and were unconditional, making *кы*, *гы* and *хы* prohibited sequences in Russian phonotactics. They only occur in a handful of mostly Turkic loanwords, such as *хычин* and *акын*, some toponyms, and *гы*, a slang onomatopoeia for crass laughter. This is a different phenomenon from the purely conventional spelling preference for *жи* and *ши* despite the vowel being technically [ы].

Thus an older genitive form of *рука* was indeed *рукы* rather than the modern *руки*, but the form **Америкы* never existed because the sound shift predates Columbus.